# update counter with button click in react

Tags: reactjs

Hi guys I am trying to make simple counter in react,using useState on this.however when I click button to increase,i don’t know how to change value and how to use setvalue function.it gives me an unknown error every time I run it.

```
import React,{useState} from "react"
function App() {
const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
function add() {
……… //count=count+1
}
return (
<div>
<h1>{count}</h1>
<button onClick={add}>+</button>
</div>
)
}export default App;
```

i tried to use setcount function,but had no luck with updating counter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use setcount function to increase count value,that’s it’s functionality.
Inside function add,call setcount and there increase your value by 1.

```
    function add(){
        setcount(count+1)  //try count+1 ,not count=count+1
        }
```

But it’s better practice not to pass state directly in setcount function.instead you should pass callback function to your state setter.

if you need the previous value of state,like here,callback function will receive old value of state as its parameter,which you can then use to determine your new value of state.in this case you are using previous value of state.

prevValue is the previous count number,before click button,that’s returned from callback function and you add 1 to this value.

```
function add(){
    setcount(prevValue=>prevValue+1)   }
```